# How to store Object in SortedList

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object-oriented-analysis, sortedlist

I have a sorted list that contains a name and a integer value. I am new to c sharp, so I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

My code:

//first class

```
class Tool {
 public Tool(string name, int quantity)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
}
```

//main class

This is a different class (2nd class)

```
 SortedList<Tool> gardeningTools = new SortedList<Tool>(); //error


        gardeningTools.Add(new Tool("nameA", 1)); //error
```

Here I am trying to add some kinds of tools inside the gardening tools. The above two lines has error says "new" is not a valid keyword and both of the lines are red. I assume it's completely a wrong way to write like that. Could anyone tell me how to write it the right way?

Comment: I don't think you want a `SortedList<Tool>` for this since a `SortedList<T>` is a "collection of key/value pairs that are sorted by the keys and are accessible by key and by index". Why did you think you wanted a `SortedList<Tool>` rather than just a `List<Tool>`?

Comment: There is no `SortedList<T>` in .NET. You should either use [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netcore-3.1) or nongeneric [`SortedList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Ah, I am not quite sure I used sorted list since I want the names in sorted order. Could you please post an answer how to do that?

Comment: Even if I use List I am not sure how to store my data inside it as it says there is no `Add` method

Comment: @IliarTurdushev Correct, that was badly written on my part.

Comment: @iachi What is it you are hoping to do with this List? To understand the difference between a `List<T>` and a `SortedList<TKey,TValue>`; the `SortedList` allows you to index with your own `Key`. For example you could write `gardeningTools["Rake"]` to return the `Tool` value "paired" with the "key", "Rake" if you had performed `gardeningTools.Add("Rake", new Tool("Rake", 1));` for example. For a normal `List<T>`, you can only index by the "positon" in the List, e.g. `gardeningTools[0]` to get the first `Tool` in the `List<Tool>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netcore-3.1) requires two generic type arguments, the type of the key and the type of the item you're storing. In your case this might be:

```
SortedList<string, Tool> gardeningTools = new SortedList<string, Tool>();
```

Assuming that `Tool` is defined something like this:

```
class Tool
{
  public Tool(string name, int quantity)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Quantity = quantity;
  }

  public string Name{get;}
  public int Quantity{get;}
}
```

Also, the `Add` method takes two parameters, the key, and the value, so you want something like this:

```
Tool tool = new Tool("nameA", 1);
gardeningTools.Add(tool.Name, tool);
```

Now you can acccess them in order. For example:

```
foreach(var tool in gardeningTools.Values)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Qty = {1}", tool.Name, tool.Quantity);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives me two error. 1) ` The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code` 2) `the gardeningtools.Add does not exists`

Comment: @iachi - I've updated the answer as it wasn't clear if your variables were member variables or local variables.

Comment: Now the first error is gone, but I still have the second error. It still says there is no Tool.Name method in Tool class. Sorry I said it wrong before. It's Tool.Name that not exist not Add

Comment: @iachi - That's right, there is no `Add` method on `Tool`, and nothing in the answer is calling `Add` on a `Tool` instance. You need to call `Add` on `gardeningTools` which is your `SortedList<string, Tool>` instance.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It's because you've written it `name` in your class declaration not `Name` as Sean has correctly used property naming convention. Using your class iachi, write `gardeningTools.Add(tool.name, tool);`

Comment: That's the error: I copy pasted it: The name 'tool' does not exist in the current context.The name 'Name' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @iachi - You're question didn't specify how you were storing you constructor parameters. I'll expand the answer.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I used tool.name now and it still gives the same error

Comment: Also, why do I have to write those 3 lines `
            SortedList<string, Tool> gardeningTools = new SortedList<string, Tool>();
            Tool tool = new Tool("nameA", 1);
            gardeningTools.Add(tool.Name, tool);` in main method? There is no error when I write inside main method or else it has the same error

Comment: @iachi - Well, you've got to write them somewhere! With a few exceptions all code that you want to run has to be inside a method or property.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Could you also mention how to print this array on console?

Comment: @iachi - I've added that to the answer